# Query data from sql table where reference is in another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and trying to query data from mysql.

Scenario -- Logged on user is Manager and wants to pull data for his team..

Explanation --

**e_users table**

```
|user_id | name    | manager_id 
---------------------------------
|1       | test    | 10
|2       | another | 1
|3       | testX   | 1
|4       | testY   | 2
|5       | testX   | 2
```

**e_details table**

```
|det_id  | detail  | user_id 
---------------------------------
|1       | sdfs    | 1
|2       | xcffgdf | 2
|3       | sdfsd   | 3
|4       | etret   | 5
|5       | cvbcvb  | 5
```

Now when user_id 1 is logged as manager, he should get data of det_id -2,3 only,

**e_details** table have data and i want to query only those data of users where whose manager is currently logged on. Means manager will pull data of users from **e_details** table.

**e_details** table have user_id, detail_comment, details_date...

and **e_users** have user_id, manager_id , ...

I tried below function, but i could not get required data

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id')
public function get_method($user_id)
{
    $this->db->join('e_users', 'e_users.manager_id = e_details.user_id','INNER');
    $this->db->where('e_details.user_id',$user_id);
    return $this->db->get('e_details')->result_array();
}
```

I think i need to join two tables and then search with common key value?

Thanks,

Comment: @VishalParkash, i received data but not of users whose manager logged in, but got manager own data, means it queried current logon user only, not complete team of manager

Comment: the e_details table contains other user's data as well??

Comment: Check and try my answer. It would solve the issue

Comment: @VishalParkash, yes e_details contains other users data as well, i am updating my question to make is more clear.

Comment: Have you tested my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well If I am getting it correct you have missed the select statement.
This would help you

```
 <?php 
        public function get_method($user_id){
    $query = $this->db->select('e_users.*, e_details.*')
            ->from('e_users')
            ->join('e_details', 'e_users.user_id = e_details.user_id', 'inner')
            ->where('e_users.manager_id',$user_id)
            ->get();
    if($query -> num_rows() > 0){
        $details_array = $query->result();
        print_r($details_array);die;
        $response['details_array'] = $details_array;
        return $response;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to query e_users, but want to get data from e_details, and only those data of users should come from e_details, where logged on user is manager of those users, sorry if i could not explain it correctly

Comment: @rjcode: really... is it working? I have updated the code just now. Please check,, This is what you are looking for..